# How can a function get the module name of the caller?

Tags: reflection, lua

Say I have two lua modules, like this.

---

Filename: `my/lua/app/caller.lua`
Module name: `my.lua.app.caller`

```lua
local reflect = require('my.lib.reflect')

-- should return "my.lua.app.caller"
reflect.get_caller_module_name()
```

---

Filename: `my/lib/reflect.lua`
Module name: `my.lib.reflect`

```lua
M = {}

function M.get_caller_module_name()
   -- magic here?
   return module_name
end

return M
```

---

Now running `my.lua.app.caller` should allow it to get its own module name, `my.lua.app.caller`. Is this doable in Lua?

*(I realize that I can get the module name by inserting `local module_name, _ = ...` as the very first line of the caller's module, but I want to be able to do this without this without needing any special modifications to the caller's module.)*

Comment: You can redefine `require` to track what is being required.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a unique and absolute module name in the first place: Module names are practically just search paths relative to a set of paths.